# Text is not sharp and shadowy in my new LCD

Tags: lcd

Quite similar to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/54824/lcd-screen-text-does-not-look-sharp), I'm in trouble of the same problem now. I'm trying to set up dual monitor on my SONY CS36H laptop, and I bought Acer **S231HLbd** last Saturday, but have been struggling with solving to get the text be sharp in these days, searched a lot, tried a lot, including all the methods in the best answer of that question, I even did more, like reinstalled NVIDIA driver, reinstalled Windows 7, tried to set gamma to some darker to let the text shadow gone. Turn off and on the clearType a few times. Changed the location of VGA cable, split the power cable and VGA cable as far as possible. Issue still there. also the screen is too white, and not healthy for eye ..

Arial font could be kind of sharp, but bold font are too fuzzy, and more other fonts look fuzzy.

I was hoping to buy DVI transistor, but posts show that it helps little for 1920x1080.

What I didn't have time and chance to do is to take the big stuff to office and try whether it is because of my laptop's video card issue, or to find some other LCD to replace and see whether that would be sharp.

Now, I'm totally exhausted .. what's left now is changing another LCD?

Comment: Have your tested turning on/off truetype settings?

Comment: @uSlackr, where to turn it on/off?

Comment: Windows 7 indexes everything.  In the search box type 'cleartype' then select the first result from the menu

Comment: Have you been tried to install Acer's monitor driver (it must be on disc with the monitor or you can find it from Acer's website)? Same thing was with my DELL U2311.

Comment: Try this one: http://support.acer.com/us/en/product/default.aspx?modelId=2253

Comment: If you do not notice the issue on your laptop's screen, but do on the external monitor, I can guarantee you that it is not your laptop.  If you try the monitor with a DVI connection on a different computer, and notice no image quality degradation, then you can blame the problem on attempting to transfer a high resolution image over an analog VGA cable.

Comment: @Anotomix hmm..that's upsetting me.. my old cd driver cannot read the CD, so I didn't install the driver .. is that the reason? (updating for your second rely) but I downloaded the 3k file and unzipped, but it's said no need to install it... :(

Answer (score 4):

In the case of 1920x1080, DVI ought to help against VGA, particularly if your VGA cable is not of a very good quality or is very long.

What made you think otherwise ?

Comment: Just note for you that long VGA cable (~50 meters) works fine without any quality lose (tested it in conference room, cable which used for projectors). So I don't think he has longer than 3 meters cable at all. And being not professional you won't see big quality change if you connect DVI against VGA.

Comment: P.S. about long VGA cable, of course it's must be accelerated by signal booster ;-)

Comment: I would argue that a DVI cable **will** be a definite improvement in picture quality compared to a VGA cable as the DVI signal is purely digital to the monitor (and thus to the pixels) whereas a vga signal has to be converted from digital to analogue to be sent down the cable and then back to a digital signal in order to be displayed, more conversion = poorer image quality.  DVI also allows direct 1:1 pixel addressing so there will be no abberations caused by slight image alignment problems.Whenever possible ditch VGA.

Comment: @Anotomix, that is completely false.  Longer cables with an analog signal will result in more noise (from external EMFs) being picked up along the length of the wire, and there will be higher ohmic losses through a longer cable, degrading the signal quality.  The same can **not** be said for digital signals, since while we are using an analog voltage transfer, the voltages represent discrete 0's and 1's.  If the voltage falls too far down, the signal will simply disappear.

Answer (score 3):

Try turning the **Screen refresh rate** up. Also, if your monitor has an **Auto Adjust** button (most new monitors have it), try pushing that after you up the refresh rate.

Comment: Acer always conducts automatically the "auto configure".. refresh rate couldn't be higher now, it's 60.

Comment: Have you tried different resolutions?

Answer (score 2):

It's possible your video card isn't pushing enough power through the video cable. Seems that the spec for this versus implementation conventions are fairly disjoint. It *may* help to try another video cable (and be quite sure both ends are firmly attached for any video cable you try). Kind of sounds more like a setting problem though.

It rarely hurts to make sure all your system updates have been installed - particularly for your video card, in this case.

Comment: lol @ "your video card isn't pushing enough power through the video cable"... how can it be possible, if there is small 4" inch devices that send signal through mini HDMI up to 1080p picture. Also he wrote about video card drivers... -1

Comment: p.s. write comment if you don't have any good answer.

Comment: @Anotomix: If you learn about DVI specs (HDMI is a subset of DVI), then compare with the cabling options, you'll notice there are many cables that fail to follow the specification. I looked in to this and found that many video cards, by a kind of symmetry, also break the specs by pushing more power than the spec requires - often much more. But if his card is following spec and the cable is damaged or non compliant, that totally could be compounding the problem. I'd appreciate it if you'd at least ask for more detail first, before downvotes. This problem may be partly config & partly hardware.

Comment: You all make the mistake of comparing a powered connection to an unpowered one.  HDMI/DVI cables just make use of digital signaling, and are not purposed for "power transfer" as in the case of a USB cable (which still uses digital signaling).  The power issue is completely different with an analog signal (i.e. VGA cable), and cable quality does matter, because power transfer relates to the final image quality.  That being said, any cable (digital or analog) that is not made up-to-spec can (and will) produce unspecified behaviour in some cases.

Comment: @Breakthrough: Umm, no, that's not a mistake. All signals have power in them, else there's no signal. Indeed the power we're talking about is tiny, but if sufficiently impeded, the message will not be correctly received - if at all.

Comment: There is no digital, it's merely an arbitrary abstraction used to "simply" the analog reality that is.

Comment: @The White Phoenix, I apologize, I was making a reference to actual power transfer between devices rather then the signal itself. Most digital signals allow a wide voltage range to trigger between logic levels, taking into account the possibility of out-of-spec cables... However, you are correct - digital is just an abstraction (thus the last statement of my previous comment).  That being said, in the case of a digital signal/cable, it either works or it doesn't - the analog voltages just represent 0's and 1's, and if the voltage drop is too much along the cable, you lose the entire signal.

Answer (score -1):

@Breakthrough - First of all, as The White Phoenix wrote all kinds of signals are powered, so it means - they use energy to translate signal through the cable. Second, my "LOL" means that if video card supports up to 1080p (an windows recognizes it), then video card must have enough power to provide such "power" to send signal through any kind of video/media cable as VGA/DVI/Display Port/SCART/S-VIDEO or HDMI. So guys if you have only "WORDS" and "NO PROOF", please don't trash this topic :/
I think author's video chip has enough power source to translate 1080p on screen and problem is only in monitor's driver, which just will fix picture Scale Proportions (Auto Adjust) and Auto Calibrate screen.
P.S. that was long time ago, when such resolution was "big/large".

Comment: You're going to be popular on this site.